# Retrieve database service name of helm subchart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am installing postgres as a dependency in my helm chart, and need to retrieve the connection details.

Postgres connection URIs in kubernetes are of the form:
`postgres://username:password@servicename.namespace.svc.cluster.local:port/dbname`

The `username`, `password`, `namespace`, `port`, and `dbname` are all easily accessible through `.Values.postgresql....`, and `.Release.Namespace`, but the [service name is initialized](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/postgresql/templates/svc.yaml) using the subchart template `common.names.fullname`.

Accessing subchart templates is [surprisingly not a thing](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3920), and probably wouldn't work anyways due to context changes.

What's a simple way to configure my application to access the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm usually content to observe that the subchart obeys the typical Helm convention of naming its objects `{{ .Release.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Name }}`.  If the subchart uses that convention, and I'm getting the database from a subchart named `postgresql`, then I can hard-code that value in my template code:

```yaml
- name: PGHOST
  value: '{{ .Release.Name }}-postgresql'
```

My experience has generally been that the Bitnami charts (and the older `stable` charts) have been pretty good about using semantic versioning, so if this name changes then the major version of the chart will change.

Answer (score 0):

The value: `{{ .Release.Name }}-postgresql` might not always be accurate. If your release name is, for example, **my-postgresql**, then the resulting value should be `my-postgresql`, not `my-postgresql-postgresql`.

To avoid such issues, it's recommended to use the template from their **templates/NOTES.txt**:

`{{ include "postgresql.v1.primary.fullname" .Subcharts.postgresql }}`