# How to override values from a parent helm chart which require templating

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm two days into Helm so maybe this is much simpler than I'm making it!

I am building a Helm chart to coordinate several services. Thanks to the hard work of others, several of those other services already have Helm charts which I wish to use as dependencies.

However, I now seem to be stuck. One of my sub-charts is postgresql from Bitnami. Another of my sub-charts is an application (again not mine) that requires a database. The application has in its templates, a reference to (among others):

```
{{ .Values.database.host }}
```

The postgresql sub-chart when applied will result in a uniquely named service endpoint, and I can resolve that from my parent like this:

```
{{ include "postgresql.v1.primary.svc.headless" .Subcharts.postgresql }}
```

but I can't find a way to then inject that into the application sub-chart that requires this to be in `{{ .Values.database.host }}`.

This seems like a really common requirement when coordinating charts, I can only assumed I've missed something really obvious as to how to do this.

Comment: Does [Retrieve database service name of helm subchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66033878/retrieve-database-service-name-of-helm-subchart) answer your question?  Helm doesn't really have a good way to do this; there's not a standard way to "publish results" out of a chart in a usable way.

Comment: (I have had some bad experiences with "umbrella" charts like you describe here, that include the entire application as dependencies.  I've had better results with tools like Helmfile that can manage several independent Helm releases, allowing the per-application charts to be self-contained.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm not sure if that post "answers" my question exactly. It seems more focused on how to get the evaluated resulted of sub-charts (which I think was basically impossible pre-helm 3.7 when I think that post was made). However, the workaround still seems applicable here in that I could opt to rely on standardised naming conventions to expect what the service name will be. That does not feel good to me because it breaks encapsulation, but I acknowledge it may be the only choice!